# function of に after 私

Tags: grammar, particle-に

sentence : あなただけの私には...今の私はなりたくない

I think it's something like "I don't want to be... only yours now", but the に there, would mean something like "for me" , "in" , "to me", etc but I can't see any possible translation where the particle fits. could you please tell what it is its function here?

Answer (score 3):

> 「あなただけの私**には**...今の私はなりたくない。」

means the same thing as:

> 「今の私は、あなただけの私**には**なりたくない。」

「X**に**なりたい」 ("to want to become X") and 「X**には**なりたくない」 ("to **not** want to become X") are both very simple constructs and the 「に」 and 「には」 **MUST** be used respectively for the phrases to make sense.  Since 「なる」 is an intransitive verb, you need to use a particle in introducing the indirect object "X".

Let us now replace the X by the actual words 「あなただけの私」("I that exists only for you" or "only yours" to borrow your TL).

The speaker is saying that, currently, she does **not** want to become the person described immediately above.

Comment: "I that exists only for you" does not make sense in English, while that is what it literally says, is it fine to understand it as (being) only yours?

Comment: I would say that it does make sense, it's just not a natural expression.

Comment: It is gramatically correct, but it does not feel natural. I.E いすのうえに いぬが います means literally "a dog exists on the chair" but that's not how we express it in English.